# Walmart API is broken for some searches

Tags: walmart-api

Several very specific search terms return very few results when the website returns 1000+ results. For example this query:

```
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/search?query=standing+desk&format=json&apiKey=[myapikey]
```

Using the search terms 'standing desk' returns:

```
{
    "query": "standing desk",
    "sort": "relevance",
    "responseGroup": "base",
    "totalResults": 8,
    "start": 1,
    "numItems": 8,
    "items": [{...}]
}
```

When there are thousands of results for 'standing desk' when searching walmart.com